# WP_query exclude a category unless it has more than one catagory

Tags: categories, wp-query

I have this category `exclude_cat` with id 39 I want to exclude it from the home. So I use for `WP_Query` args like this:

```
$args = array (
  'category__not_in' => array( 39 ), //exclude ID
);
```

Works. But now I want to only exclude it if is the only category on the post.
So exclude the `exclude_cat` post only if it is the only category of the post, if it has `exclude_cat` and `random_cat` I do want to include it.

Is there a way to do this using `WP_Query`?
If not what's the best way to do this otherwise?

Comment: Do you have pagination on your home page?

Comment: Yes, I thought about loading far to much and skipping these inside the loop but that would break the pagination. Any ideas?

Comment: I am fairly sure you can't do this with any query functions. You will probably have to create a filter for `posts_where` and directly alter the SQL.

Comment: ahh yes, didn't think about that Will try it tomorrow. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up with this to exclude the *mama* category:

```php
    /**
     * filter home and blog pages for mama category
     * exclude posts that have that category unless they have more categories
     * @param string $where
     * @return string
     */
    function filter_mama_cat( $where) {
        global $wpdb;
        // get the term to exclude
        $term = get_term_by('slug', 'mama', 'category');
        // only on home and blog pages
        if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
            $where .= 'AND (
            ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID NOT IN (
                SELECT object_id
                FROM ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . '
                WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (' . $term->term_id . ')
            )
            OR 1 <
            (   SELECT count(*) AS "count"
                FROM ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . '
                JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . ' ON ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . '.term_taxonomy_id = ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . '.term_taxonomy_id
                WHERE ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . '.taxonomy = "category" AND ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . '.object_id = ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID
                GROUP BY ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . '.object_id
            )
        )';
        }
        return $where;
    }
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_mama_cat');
```

For theme purposes use it in `functions.php`.

Comment: this works fine, only issue i am having is, that you hardcoded the table names and that includes the table prefixes. you could call `global wpdb;` and then use it inside your string (you will need to use double quotes => " instead of single ones => '). so instead of writing `wp_posts.ID` you could write `{$wpdb->posts}.ID`.

Comment: @honk31 you are correct. I updated the code. Thanks for noticing on this 9,5 year old answer :)

Comment: props to you my friend, your code still works fine :)